# Concatenate two fields with case condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can i concatenate 2 fields but i have also CASE condition. Here is my sql:

```
INSERT INTO #TempTable([Name],[TotalBets])
SELECT      CASE
                WHEN @Limited ='All'
                    THEN DPL.[FirstName]
                WHEN @Limited ='Blind_No'                   
                    THEN DPL.[FirstName]            
                ELSE '*****'
                END AS DPL.[FirstName] + ' ' + 
            CASE
                WHEN @Limited ='All'
                    THEN DPL.[LastName]
                WHEN @Limited ='Blind_No'
                    AND [BlindAccount] = 1
                    THEN '*****'
                WHEN @Limited ='Blind_No'
                    AND [BlindAccount] = 0
                    THEN DPL.[LastName]
                ELSE '*****'
                END AS DPL.[LastName] [Name],
        SUM(FWA.TotalBetAmount)                     [TotalBets]     
    FROM [WarehouseMgmt].[FactWalletAgr] FWA
    JOIN [WarehouseMgmt].[DimPlayer] DPL ON FWA.[PlayerId] = DPL.[Id]
    JOIN [WarehouseMgmt].[DimGame] DG ON FWA.[GameId] = DG.[Id] 
GROUP BY DPL.[FirstName] + ' ' + DPL.[LastName]
```

But this query is wrong, and i don't know how to concatenate when i have CASE condition.
Any help or suggestion ?

Comment: Specify data you have and expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not use alias names in group by clause. I have changed it like below. If you are using above versions of sql server 2008 then use `concat` function. Doing concatenation b/w two strings will results to `NULL` some times.

```
INSERT INTO #TempTable([Name],[TotalBets])
    SELECT     ( CASE
                    WHEN @Limited ='All'
                        THEN DPL.[FirstName]
                    WHEN @Limited ='Blind_No'                   
                        THEN DPL.[FirstName]            
                    ELSE '*****'
                    END) + ' ' + 
               ( CASE
                    WHEN @Limited ='All'
                        THEN DPL.[LastName]
                    WHEN @Limited ='Blind_No'
                        AND [BlindAccount] = 1
                        THEN '*****'
                    WHEN @Limited ='Blind_No'
                        AND [BlindAccount] = 0
                        THEN DPL.[LastName]
                    ELSE '*****'
                    END ) [Name],
            SUM(FWA.TotalBetAmount)                     [TotalBets]     
        FROM [WarehouseMgmt].[FactWalletAgr] FWA
        JOIN [WarehouseMgmt].[DimPlayer] DPL ON FWA.[PlayerId] = DPL.[Id]
        JOIN [WarehouseMgmt].[DimGame] DG ON FWA.[GameId] = DG.[Id] 
    GROUP BY    ( CASE
                    WHEN @Limited ='All'
                        THEN DPL.[FirstName]
                    WHEN @Limited ='Blind_No'                   
                        THEN DPL.[FirstName]            
                    ELSE '*****'
                    END) + ' ' + 
               ( CASE
                    WHEN @Limited ='All'
                        THEN DPL.[LastName]
                    WHEN @Limited ='Blind_No'
                        AND [BlindAccount] = 1
                        THEN '*****'
                    WHEN @Limited ='Blind_No'
                        AND [BlindAccount] = 0
                        THEN DPL.[LastName]
                    ELSE '*****'
                    END )
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the `case` and concatenation in a derived table. `Group by` its result.

```
select [Name], sum(TotalBetAmount) as [TotalBets]
from
(
SELECT      CASE
                WHEN @Limited ='All'
                    THEN DPL.[FirstName]
                WHEN @Limited ='Blind_No'                   
                    THEN DPL.[FirstName]            
                ELSE '*****'
                END + ' ' + 
            CASE
                WHEN @Limited ='All'
                    THEN DPL.[LastName]
                WHEN @Limited ='Blind_No'
                    AND [BlindAccount] = 1
                    THEN '*****'
                WHEN @Limited ='Blind_No'
                    AND [BlindAccount] = 0
                    THEN DPL.[LastName]
                ELSE '*****'
                END AS [Name],
            FWA.TotalBetAmount AS TotalBetAmount 
    FROM [WarehouseMgmt].[FactWalletAgr] FWA
    JOIN [WarehouseMgmt].[DimPlayer] DPL ON FWA.[PlayerId] = DPL.[Id]
    JOIN [WarehouseMgmt].[DimGame] DG ON FWA.[GameId] = DG.[Id] 
) dt
GROUP BY [Name]
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem with your query is the `as` in the middle of the expression -- and the use of aliases with periods in them.  Perhaps this solves your problem:

```
INSERT INTO #TempTable([Name],[TotalBets])
    SELECT ( (CASE WHEN @Limited = 'All' THEN DPL.[FirstName]
                   WHEN @Limited = 'Blind_No' THEN DPL.[FirstName]            
                   ELSE '*****'
              END)+ ' ' + 
              (CASE WHEN @Limited = 'All' THEN DPL.[LastName]
                    WHEN @Limited = 'Blind_No' AND [BlindAccount] = 1 THEN '*****'
                    WHEN @Limited ='Blind_No' AND [BlindAccount] = 0
                    THEN DPL.[LastName]
              ELSE '*****'
             END)
            ) as [Name],
            SUM(FWA.TotalBetAmount) as [TotalBets]     
    FROM [WarehouseMgmt].[FactWalletAgr] FWA JOIN
         [WarehouseMgmt].[DimPlayer] DPL
         ON FWA.[PlayerId] = DPL.[Id] JOIN
         [WarehouseMgmt].[DimGame] DG
         ON FWA.[GameId] = DG.[Id] 
    GROUP BY DPL.[FirstName] + ' ' + DPL.[LastName];
```

This assumes that you don't want to combine the "blind" names into a single row.